# How to tell Symfony to ignore certain files in /translations

Tags: symfony, translation

How can I tell Symfony to ignore a file with a certain suffix in the Bundle's /translations directory?

for example, I would like it to ignore the .pot file but if I put one there, it then tries to load it and cannot find a loader.